# get @hide property via reflection

Tags: android, reflection

I have use follow code get localDisplayMetrics .

```
DisplayMetrics localDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((WindowManager) getSystemService("window")).getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(localDisplayMetrics);
```

I want to get `localDisplayMetrics.noncompatWidthPixels`.Can I get it via reflection?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DisplayMetrics localDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(localDisplayMetrics);

try {
    Field field = DisplayMetrics.class.getDeclaredField("noncompatWidthPixels");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    int value = field.getInt(localDisplayMetrics);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I see you're new to StackOverflow. If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.